# Ruby on Rails best way to update 100k records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am in a situation where I have to update more than 100k records in the database with best efficient way Please see below my code:

```
namespace :order do
  desc "update confirmed at field for Payments::Order"
  task set_confirmed_at: :environment do
    puts "==> Updating confirmed_at for orders starts ...".blue
    Payments::Order.find_each(batch_size: 10000) do |orders|
      order_action = orders.actions.where("sender LIKE ?", "%ConfirmJob%").first if orders.actions
      if !order_action.blank?
        orders.update_attribute(:confirmed_at, order_action.created_at)
        puts "order id = #{orders.id} has been updated.".green
      end
    end
    puts "== completed ==".blue
  end
end
```

Here I am breaking records into 10000 of each batch size and then try to update the record on the basis of some conditions so could anyone suggest me a more efficient way to do the same task.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You can try update_all:

```
Payments::Order.joins(:actions).where(Payment::OrderAction.arel_table[:sender].matches("%ConfirmJob%")).update_all("confirmed_at = actions.created_at")
```

So your code will look like this:

```
namespace :order do
  desc "update confirmed at field for Payments::Order"
  task set_confirmed_at: :environment do
    puts "==> Updating confirmed_at for orders starts ...".blue
    Payments::Order.joins(:actions).where(Payments::OrderAction.arel_table[:sender].matches("%ConfirmJob%")).update_all("confirmed_at = actions.created_at")
    puts "== completed ==".blue
  end
end
```

**Update**:
I've investigated an issue and found out that [bulk update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476096/bulk-updating-a-joined-table-with-activerecord-update-all-and-rails-4) with joined table is a long term issue [in rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/522)
As `set` part uses string parameter as it is I suggest to add from clause there.

```
namespace :order do
    desc "update confirmed at field for Payments::Order"
      task set_confirmed_at: :environment do
        puts "==> Updating confirmed_at for orders starts ...".blue
          Payments::Order.joins(:actions).
                where(Order::Action.arel_table[:sender].matches("%ConfirmJob%")).
                update_all("confirmed_at = actions.created_at FROM actions")
        puts "== completed ==".blue
      end
    end
```

Comment: A quick warning. The *#update_all* although quick doesn't instantiate model instances. This means no callbacks (like *after_create*, *before_update*, etc.) will trigger when using this method.

Comment: Hi, Alexander, I was getting an error **uninitialized constant Payment** so I changed your code to `where(Payments::OrderAction.arel_table[:sender].matches("%ConfirmJob%"))` then again I got error that **uninitialized constant Payments::OrderAction**  Now I have changed it to `where(Order::Action.arel_table[:sender].matches("%ConfirmJob%"))` but now I got different error **ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "actions"
LINE 1: UPDATE "payments_orders" SET confirmed_at = actions.created_..**

Comment: Updated the response.

Comment: Hi alex this query is fine but each order has different confirmed_at time but your query will update same for all orders right?

Comment: No. It will set confirmed at from actions.created_at related to order

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `Payments::Order.find_each` so your solution will loop for each `Payment::Order` when you only want to loop for the ones having `actions.server like '%ConfirmJob%'`, so I will go with this solution:

```
Payments::Order
  .includes(:actions)
  .joins(:actions)
  .where("actions.server like '%?%'", "ConfirmJob")
  .find_each do |order|
    order_action = order.actions.first
    order.update!(confirmed_at: order_action.created_at)
end
```